# Multi-threading optimization in-depth

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

A time ago I participated in an interview process where I was tasked with a simple requirement. I created the best solution I could, using some lock-free implementation.
I didn't pass the code challenge, and sadly I didn't get any feedback neither, so I never learned how the ideal solution would look like. I didn't get the chance to ask any question neither, I just got the requirement from the recruiter and had to send the solution back in 2 days. The recruiter just said "we are not moving forward".

Since then I've been trying to learn and improve the solution, but I feel like I am not really making any progress.

So, what I'd like is to get guidance and lectures, or any recommendation that can lead me in the right direction. Of course, code snippets are more than welcome, but the topic is really interesting to me, so I am looking for knowledge.

### This is the requirement:

```c#
//Please fill in the implementation of the service defined below. This service is to keep track
//of ids to return if they have been seen before. No 3rd party packages can be used and the method
//must be thread-safe to call.

//create the implementation as efficiently as possible in both locking, memory usage, and CPU usage
public interface IDuplicateCheckService
{
    // Checks the given id and returns if it is the first time we have seen it
    // IT IS CRITICAL that duplicates are not allowed through this system but false
    // positives can be tolerated at a maximum error rate of less than 1%
    bool IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(int id);
}

public class HighlyOptimizedThreadSafeDuplicateCheckService 
    : IDuplicateCheckService
{
    public bool IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(int id) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

### One of the first things I've noticed is this:

> false positives can be tolerated at a maximum error rate of less than
> 1%

I don't even understand under what circumtances this is possible.

### Some of the implementations I've done

This was the initial solution I created. It is a simple locking solution

```c#
public class LockDuplicateCheckService : IDuplicateCheckService
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _itemsSeen = new();
    private readonly object _lock = new();

    public bool IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(int id)
    {
        if (_itemsSeen.Contains(id))
        {
            return true;
        }

        lock (_lock)
        {
            return _itemsSeen.Add(id) == false;
        }
    }
}
```

After some refactoring, and some brain-refreshing research, I came up with a lock-free solution using ReaderWriterLock:

```c#
public class ReaderWriterLockDuplicateCheckService : IDuplicateCheckService
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _itemsSeen = new();
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new();

    public bool IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(int id)
    {
        _lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            if (_itemsSeen.Contains(id))
            {
                return true;
            }

            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                return _itemsSeen.Add(id) == false;
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

I also gave a try to a ConcurrentDictionary, which is probably the easiest but the worst in terms of performance.

```c#
public class ConcurrentDictionaryDuplicateCheckService : IDuplicateCheckService
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool> _itemsSeen = new();

    public bool IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(int id)
    {
        return _itemsSeen.TryAdd(id, false) == false;
    }
}
```

### Benchmark

I also created a benchmark using BenchmarkDotNet:

```c#
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchy>();
    }

    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class Benchy
    {
        private readonly int[] ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 1_000_000).ToArray();

        [Benchmark]
        public void Lock()
        {
            var service = new LockDuplicateCheckService();
            Parallel.ForEach(
                ids,
                currentId => service.IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(currentId));
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ReaderWriterLock()
        {
            var service = new ReaderWriterLockDuplicateCheckService();
            Parallel.ForEach(
                ids,
                currentId => service.IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(currentId));
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ConcurrentDictionary()
        {
            var service = new ConcurrentDictionaryDuplicateCheckService();
            Parallel.ForEach(
                ids,
                currentId => service.IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen(currentId));
        }
    }
}
```

### These are the results

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lock | 65.20 ms | 1.294 ms | 1.977 ms | 64.73 ms | 875.0000 | 875.0000 | 875.0000 | 41 MB |
| ReaderWriterLock | 135.34 ms | 6.795 ms | 20.034 ms | 130.18 ms | 1000.0000 | 1000.0000 | 1000.0000 | 41 MB |
| ConcurrentDictionary | 227.55 ms | 5.921 ms | 16.307 ms | 224.06 ms | 15000.0000 | 6000.0000 | 1666.6667 | 99 MB |

### Questions:

1. If you were my reviewer, why wouldn't you have hired me?
2. What would you expect to see in the solution?
3. What does "false positives rate below 1%" mean?
4. What do you recommend me exploring/learning?

Comment: The biggest red flag I see here is that when you realised you didn't understand the requirement _you didn't ask_, but just ignored part of the requirement. That to me is far more important than any code. But [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: You are right, It is just that there was no chance to ask, I got the requirement (just the interface with the comments as the explanation) from the recruiter and I had to return the solution 2 days after. They never came back with any answers, rather a "we are not moving forward"

Comment: With the talk about the false positive rate the question is steering you very much towards bloom filters. Not sure where you are deriving the concurrency requirements from. If that wasn't asked, this looks like an overcomplication. But it's a bullshit interview task that just checks your familiarity with niche data structures.

Comment: I added the whole requiriment including the whole comment, where the thread-safe statements was originally.
The Bloom Filter seems to be the approach, which is great to know!!
Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have a glaring logic error. `IsThisTheFirstTimeWeHaveSeen` returns true if the ID is already seen; it should return false.

Comment: Side note: lock-free means no locks. That doesn't appear in your requirements, and your "lock-free" implementation has a lock.

Comment: You are right, I didn't include the version using SpinLocks to avoid redundancy. My assumption was that "lock efficiency" was expecting some lock-free implementation.
Thank you!